# Array not being fully parsed in C program

Tags: c, arrays, stdio

I am trying to build a program that parses an array of chars from input and then returns a formatted omitting extra whites spaces.

```
#include <stdio.h>
# include <ctype.h>
/* count charecters in input; 1st version */
int main(void)
{

  int ch, outp=0;
  char str[1000], nstr[1000];
  /* collect the data string */
  while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && outp < 1000){
    str[outp] = ch;
    outp++;
  }
  for (int j = 0; j < outp-1; j++){
    printf("%c",str[j]);
  }

  printf("\n");
  for (int q = 0; q < outp-1; q++)
    {
      if (isalpha(str[q]) && isspace(str[q+1])){
        for(int i = 0; i < outp; i++){
          if (isspace(str[i]) && isspace(i+1)){
            continue;
          }
          nstr[i] = str[i];
        }
      }
    }
  printf("\n");

  printf("Formated Text: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < outp-1; i++){
     printf("%c", nstr[i]);
  }
  //putchar("\n");c
  // printf("1");

return 0;
}
```

Here is my code. The array is never fully parsed, the end is usually omitted, odd chars show up and past attempts have yielded a not fully parsed array, Why?
  This is exercise 1-9 from "the C programming language".

Comment: The number of characters in `nstr` could be considerably less than in `str`. Yet you still output `outp - 1` characters from `nstr`, which could lead to you printing uninitialized (and indeterminate) parts of `nstr`.

Comment: The logic for stripping out spaces isn’t right because it needs to copy characters to a different location once an extra space has been skipped. So you need an additional index which is only incremented when a character has been copied. And then you have to make sure the final character is copied (if it isn’t a stripped out space).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

a) You need to use an additional index variable while copying the characters from `str` to `nstr`. Do something like -

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < outp -1; i++){
      if (isspace(str[i]) && isspace(i+1)){
        continue;
      }
      nstr[j++] = str[i];
    }
```

b) While you are printing `nstr`, you are using the length of the original string `str`. The length of `nstr` will be less than that of `str` since you have removed the spaces.

You need to find the length of `nstr` now or use `i < strlen(nstr) -1` in the condition.

Comment: There are no null terminators on these arrays so not a good idea to use `strlen()`

Comment: And you have a problem with the last character, because you check the character after it.

Comment: Still not right - now you don't copy the final character. Suggest you test it with some relevant data, which you appear not to have done.